# Word for advice that is too obvious to be helpful?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that describes advice that is too obvious to be helpful. Imagine asking for advice, and someone responds with simply saying to "do what is desirable" or "avoid what is undesirable" in the context of the advice.

For example, if you asked someone for exam prep advice, and they simply said "don't fail", or if you asked for advice in marathon preparation and someone said "don't get tired".

One might use the adjective as follows: "Please spare your ____ advice"

Comment: Hollow responses are also *begging-the-question* answers as they contain no substance.

Comment: How about "self-evident" ? [Definition of](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/self-evident) : A fact or situation that is *self-evident* is so obvious that there is no need for proof or explanation. Examples: It is self-evident that we will never have enough resources to meet the demand.
The implications for this country are self-evident.